# why Codeigniter Adding .html in form action automatically?

Tags: codeigniter

I have the following code in my controller:

```
$data['action']='contact/add';
$this->load->view('inc/header');
$this->load->view('contact',$data);
$this->load->view('inc/footer');
```

and when I load my view page it renders the following form element:

```
<form
  action="http://someurl.com/index.php/Booknow/add.html" 
  id="registrationform"
  class="row" name="registrationform"
  method="post"
  accept-charset="utf-8">
```

What is the reason I am not able to find anything on this?

Comment: you should call like this `foldername/ControllerName/FunctionName` example `www.domain.com/HomeController/myFun`

Comment: i have done same as you have suggested but there is no diffrance at all ?

Comment: see your action url it has `.html` change it to controller name like this `action="http://someurl.com/index.php/Booknow/add"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's already documented [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html#adding-a-url-suffix)(Url suffix configuration), and the reason is it's on the configuration not in your controller, view or HTML.

```php
With empty url suffix:
site_url('foo/bar'): http://localhost/ap.programming/foo/bar
base_url('bar/bas'): http://localhost/ap.programming/bar/bas

With '.jsp' as url suffix:
site_url('foo/bar'): http://localhost/ap.programming/foo/bar.jsp
base_url('bar/bas'): http://localhost/ap.programming/bar/bas
```

P.S:

> Deliberately taking Codeigniter 4 out of consideration.

Note: It's good to include the PHP view (undendered HTML) and the rendered HTML into the question (an advice to your next question).

Comment: is it not answering?